# Generate Insert statement with "@" for SQLCommand?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

If I use SQLCommand, I usually need something like:

```
INSERT INTO klant(klant_id,naam,voornaam) VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)";
```

Is there some easy way I can generate this string?

SSMS generate something like this

```
           ,[years]
       ,[source]
       ,[TimeStamp])
 VALUES
       (<count, int,>
       ,<sex_male, bit,>
       ,<Ethnicity, tinyint,>
```

Can I use it somehow?

Comment: highlight the generated template code and press shift-ctrl-M.  Then type the desired parameter names as the values in the dialog box.  If this need is for .NET application code, you can generate a parameterized statement using SqlCommandBuilder (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz(v=vs.110).aspx).  This will generate the needed command text and a strongly typed parameter collection with parameter names like `@p1`, `@p2`, etc.

Comment: @DanGuzman - That is a lot of typing because you can't just copy the parameter names from the left to the right.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this frequently then consider SSMS tools pack. This [generates CRUD according to user specified templates](http://ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=12).

An adhoc not particularly robust alternative is pretty simple with find and replace though.

SSMS generates something like

```
INSERT INTO [HumanResources].[Employee]
           ([BusinessEntityID]
           ,[NationalIDNumber]
           ,[LoginID]
           ,[CurrentFlag]
           ,[rowguid]
           ,[ModifiedDate])
     VALUES
           (<BusinessEntityID, int,>
           ,<NationalIDNumber, nvarchar(15),>
           ,<LoginID, nvarchar(256),>
           ,<CurrentFlag, Flag,>
           ,<rowguid, uniqueidentifier,>
           ,<ModifiedDate, datetime,>)
```

Then copy the top section down to the bottom

```
INSERT INTO [HumanResources].[Employee]
           ([BusinessEntityID]
           ,[NationalIDNumber]
           ,[LoginID]
           ,[CurrentFlag]
           ,[rowguid]
           ,[ModifiedDate])
     VALUES
           ([BusinessEntityID]
           ,[NationalIDNumber]
           ,[LoginID]
           ,[CurrentFlag]
           ,[rowguid]
           ,[ModifiedDate])
```

And select the bottom section and replace `[` with `@` and `]` with an empty string.

Or alternatively it would be fairly trivial to write something that queries `sys.columns` and generates the desired string.

(Again a not robust solution that assumes you are using column names conforming to the rules for standard identifiers- `quotename` would help with the column names but not the parameter names if you aren't.)

```
DECLARE @QualifiedName NVARCHAR(500) = '[HumanResources].[Employee]';

WITH C
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   sys.columns
         WHERE  object_id = object_id(@QualifiedName)
                AND is_computed = 0
                AND is_identity = 0)
SELECT '
INSERT INTO ' + @QualifiedName + '
           (' + SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + name
                                  FROM   C
                                  ORDER  BY column_id
                                  FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 8000) + ')
     VALUES
           (' + SUBSTRING((SELECT ',@' + name
                                  FROM   C
                                  ORDER  BY column_id
                                  FOR XML PATH('')), 3, 8000) + ')
```